# Android Studio no longer shows build directory in project pane's project tree

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio used to show my build directories as orange directories in the project tab when displaying as "Project" (as opposed to the "Android" view). Now the only way I can verify if the build succeeded is to open a file browser or a terminal. How can I unhide the build directory and display all items in my directory via the Project pane? i.e. I don't want Android Studio filtering/hiding anything. I want to see everything in the directory.

OS: Ubuntu 20.4

Android Studio:

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922, built on July 27, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.4.0-80-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.thoughtworks.gauge, org.intellij.plugins.markdown
Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the settings icon on the project tab and make sure "Show Excluded Files" is checked.